# Tengo un problema con un algoritmo algo complejo

Tags: javascript, algoritmos

Tengo siete puestos, cada puesto cuenta con 4 divisiones, el salario del puesto 1 en la division 1 aumenta 0, en la división 2 aumenta 3, en la división 3 aumenta 6, en la división 4 aumenta 9 (Tienen un aumento de 3).
En el puesto 2, división 1 aumenta 12, división 2 aumenta 16, división 3 aumenta 20, división 4 aumenta 24 (aumento de 4), y así mismo el puesto 3 tiene un incremento de 5.
El puesto 4 tiene un incremento de 10.
El puesto 5 tiene un incremento de 15.
El puesto 6 tiene un incremento de 30.
Ejemplo si ya estaba en el puesto 2, división 1 y sube a puesto 2 y la división 2, su salario aumenta 4
Ejemplo si ya estaba en el puesto 3, division 1 y sube a puesto 4 y la división 3, su salario aumenta 45
Obviamente no se puede pasar del puesto 4 al 3, ni del puesto 4 division 4 al puesto 4 division 1.
Pero necesito un algoritmo para realizar estos calculos, tienen alguna idea?
Espero haberme dado a entender.
Gracias por adelantado a quien pueda ayudarme.

Comment: Pues eso resulta ser una tabla, no entiendo que ocupas calcular como algoritmo, puedes hacer una estructura switch case y listo...

Comment: Bueno, parece que no me expliqué muy bien, pero lo que quiero calcular como algoritmo es: Si estoy en el puesto 4 en la división 3 y subo al puesto 5 en la división 3, ¿Cuál es el nuevo salario? Esto podría hacerse con muchos if, pero quiero buscar la forma de evitar tantas validaciones.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y [mcve]. Es **necesario** que aportes el código de lo que hayas intentado, de lo contrario será difícil ayudarte. Las preguntas mal formuladas terminan cerradas. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer 7 vectores llamados como el numero del puesto y que contengan los valores de multiplicación de los aumentos ejemplo:

```
int[4] uno = [0, 3, 6, 9];
int[4] dos = [12, 16, 20, 24];
.
.
.
```

Una vez con esto y la entrada resuelves buscando el numero de división dentro del vector, por ejemplo:

```
Entrada: 
antes = 2, 1; 
ahora = 2, 2;
```

Con esto primero evalúas si es posible, es decir si no vas para atrás, en el caso de mi entrada esta bien (eso con if's) después solo buscas en el vector:

```
int IndiceDeMultiplicacionDeSalario = dos[2-1]; (el -1 es por la posición en el vector)
```

creo que así es mas simple que con muchos if's, pero depende de muchos factores, la pregunta no es muy especifica...

Comment: Gracias por responder. Pero en el sitio evitamos responder preguntas que no estén claras o que están mal formuladas. Por otro lado, el OP ha usado la etiqueta `Javascript` y tu código está en Java (muy diferente). Te invito a leer [answer]. Saludos